# Erlang Cowboy - Dependency crypto is specified as a dependency but is not reachable by the system

Tags: erlang, cowboy

I have installed Erlang vesion 19.3 on CentOS 7 linux server. Yesterday, I downloaded Cowboy HTTP server (latest version). In the examples/hello_world directory I have run `make` (version 4.1) command and got the following error

`Dependency crypto is specified as a dependency but is not reachable by the system.`

Can anyone help me to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`crypto` should be part of your Erlang distribution since it is part of standard library.  But if you look closer into documentation you can find that

> The current implementation of the Erlang Crypto application is based on the OpenSSL package version 0.9.7 or higher. There are source and binary releases on the web.
>
> Source releases of OpenSSL can be downloaded from the [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) project homepage, or mirror sites listed there.

I would guess that you have those missing. In fact, standard Erlang installation will notify you if binary are missing (package manager might be suppressing those messages)

```
APPLICATIONS DISABLED (See: ~.kerl/builds/19.3/otp_build_19.3.log)
* crypto         : No usable OpenSSL found
* ssh            : No usable OpenSSL found
* ssl            : No usable OpenSSL found
```

Just try to install some OpenSSL implementation from your package manager and reinstall Erlang.

As footnote [kerl](https://github.com/kerl/kerl) is a good project for managing, testing and fine tuning you VM.